# Mail Insists on Being "Push"

Tags: email, push-notifications

Phone: Sprint Nexus S 4G with the ICS update.

I have email accounts (hosted Exchange) set up and working without issue. Well, one small issue: No matter what "Check Frequency" I choose, they insist on being "push" mode. I have one at 10 minutes, the other at 15 minutes -- but the second an email hits that inbox the phone dings.

Drives me nuts -- and wreaks havoc with playing music...

Is there a setting somewhere else or new in ICS that I need to be looking for? Anyone else having a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your hosted Exchange provider to turn the Push off. They are enforcing it.

Another way: Turn your email notification off or set its ringtone 'Silent'. But, its inconvenient.

Comment: Interesting idea. The hosted Exchange provider, in both cases, is Office365. I'll poke around the admin control panels today and see if anything pops up.

Comment: This was, indirectly, the answer.  I had to delete and recreate the accounts. As part of the creation process there were new prompts about sync frequency.  More at http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/160/p/54767/196231.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install Juicedefender and set it to only allow data connections with the interval you want. You might need one of the paid versions if you need this to work on WiFi as well.